# Converting link list from C to C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a working linked list implementation in C (from linux) which I want to convert for use in C++ (on windows).

I have a player struct, which looks like this:

```
typedef struct PLAYER {
    char * name;
    struct PLAYER * next;
} player;
```

In my original C code, I initialised the player list like this:

```
player * player_list;
player_list = malloc(sizeof(player));
```

However, for use in C, I cannot use (void *), so I need to cast it like this:

```
player * player_list;
player_list = (player*)malloc(sizeof(player));
```

For usage of adding/linking players, I check whether items in the linked list are set to `NULL`, however after some debugging I can see that in C++ the malloc'ed data is not set to `NULL` like it is in C.

For example, in the C implementation `current->next == NULL` is true, while in C++ it is false.

My question is, how do I malloc data in C++ so the data is set to be `NULL` by default? Thereby permitting me to use my original functions.

Comment: Why not go through it with a loop and set each value to NULL?

Comment: You want a quick conversion?  `#include <list> struct player { std::string name; }; std::list<player> player_list;`

Comment: Any reason to not use any of the collections (list/forward list, vector et cetera) provided in the standard library? If you want to move to "proper" C++ you really don't want to use malloc/free at all, but new/delete instead (or preferably smart pointers or existing collections).

Comment: *Thereby permitting me to use my original functions.* -- Then you're not serious about learning C++ if you want to go back and use the original `C` functions.  C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: @OP [Creation of a linked list, and adding 3 items to it](http://ideone.com/2BFktC)

Comment: In C, it's best to get into the habit of immediately initialising all pointers in any heap structure you create to null. Then fill them in, often with further calls to malloc(). If malloc() fails, you will need to destroy the partly-built structure, so it is important not to have dangling pointers. Doing it explicitly helps you to remember. In C++, constructors and destructors do this for you.

Comment: I was not aware that C guaranteed malloc'd memory to be zero filled. Maybe you've just been lucky until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *need* to make a linked list in C++, you should use operator `new` for allocating memory and you don't need `typedef`.

```
struct Node
{
  std::string name;
  Node * next;
};

// creating a new node
Node * p_node = new Node;
Node.name = "John";
Node.next = nullptr;
```

Note the change from `char[]` to `std::string`.  The `std::string` type should be used for text since it handles allocation and deallocation for the text content.

Also, you'll eventually want to use `template` so that you can apply the linked list data structure to different node types.

Or you can simplify your life and use `std::list`, as in:

```
std::list<name> name_database;
```

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, how do I malloc data in C++ so the data is set to be NULL by default? Thereby permitting me to use my original functions.

You don't need to.

The simplest way to convert your code to a linked list in c++ is

```
 struct PLAYER {
     std::string name;
 };
```

and use

```
 std::list<PLAYER> player_list;
```

The [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container class already implements a linked list right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The function that allocates memory and initializes it to zero is [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc). It's the same for C++ and C, `malloc` does not zero-out the memory, but `calloc` does. It was a 'coincidence' that it 'worked' in C.

To fully take advantage of C++, you could use a standard library container like [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory).

Answer (score 2):

Although I'd advise you to fully embrace C++ and move to the STL containers, I'm guessing you want to do the minimal work to get your unit tests back up and running before you start.  I'm writing this to give you the minimum changes you need to get to the stage where you can start refactoring against your tests.

Add a constructor to your struct:

```
struct PLAYER {
    char * name;
    struct PLAYER * next;
    PLAYER()
        : name(), next()
    {}
};
```

or, using a recent C++ to minimise the change:

```
struct PLAYER {
    char *name = nullptr;
    struct PLAYER *next = nullptr;
};
```

Then you can replace your `calloc()` or `malloc()` with a simple `new PLAYER()` and the matching `free()` with `delete`, and be ready to start your refactoring.

Some of the first things you'll change to be more idiomatic C++ are the raw pointers - you'll want to use `std::string` instead of `char*`, and `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for most other pointers (the `PLAYER*` in your linked list will disappear when you move to a standard container).

Comment: Yes, but this appears just to be a stepping stone to the Right Thing, so I'm just showing the minimum to get the unit tests working, and no more.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  I meant a compiler for a recent standard, rather than the code following modern idioms.  I've made it clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how do I `malloc` data in C++ so the data is set to be NULL by default?

There is no way you can dynamically allocate memory for a pointer in C++ *or* C that either standard ensures will result in the pointer initially being `NULL`.  In practice, allocating with `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` is likely to have this effect, because it initializes all allocated bytes to 0.  Although pointer representations with all bytes `0` are commonly representations of `NULL` pointers, however, the standard does not *require* them to be.  (This is distinct from the question of the source-code representation of a null pointer constant.)  Nevertheless, if you're concerned only with Windows and MSVC++ then `calloc()` should do the trick for you.

Whether it's worthwhile to pursue this course is an altogether different question.  C++ does provide suitable collection templates so that you don't need to work out such details, and these will interact cleanly with other STL templates, which is much to your advantage.  There are few reasons not to do so; the only one that comes immediately to mind is that you want to be able to build the project successfully and correctly with either a C or a C++ compiler.  In that case, the constraint that any changes must avoid altering the code's C semantics is huge and non-trivial.